# webcam is not detected in Ubuntu 18.04 in HP G6

Tags: webcam

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 in my HP G6 laptop the webcam is not detected. I ran lsusb and it shows -

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 040: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am new in ubuntu. Any help to restore the webcam is appreciable.

Comment: If the Lenovo device is the webcam and not something else, it might be worth running `lsusb -v` for more detail.